# Netbeans 8.2 fails to start from the Desktop

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

This may possibly be connected to another question, and for that, I truly apologize, but what I've noticed now is, after correcting an issue with getting Java code to run via clearing the caches on NetBeans, now NetBeans won't even run. This is rather strange as the program was working perfectly before.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue? I would add some pictures, but the issue can't really be explained through a picture.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried starting the machine. That was sort of the first thing I did.